# Chaining grep in bash alias

Tags: bash, grep

I have a bash alias for all users in /etc/profile.d/sh_aliases. One of the aliases is as follows:

`alias nlanhosts = 'nmap -sn 192.168.0.* | grep "[0-9]* hosts up" | grep -o "[0-9]*"'`

When I try running the above command normally (i.e. without alias or single quotes) I get a single number. However with the alias, I get 4 numbers printed out. I can't work out why the behaviour is different when aliased. I tried using it as a function and it made no difference. Are there any characters I need to escape when making aliases?

Comment: Wrong alias syntax.

Comment: set a debug option `set -x` and run your alias in terminal. Does command differs from defined in alias or it same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work?

```
alias nlanhosts='nmap -sn 192.168.0.* | grep -o "[0-9]* hosts up" | grep -o "[0-9]*"'
```

Just added -o for the first grep also.

Also try to use `192.168.0.0/24` or `192.168.0.1-255` format than *

Comment: Yes! I have no idea why this behaves as it should but thanks :)

Comment: its because the last grep matches all the numbers in the output line. For example the following output <br/>
`Nmap done: 256 IP addresses (73 hosts up) scanned in 1.91 seconds`<br/>

your regex matches 256, 73, 1 and 91 so you are getting 4 outputs but you are looking for just 73 so adding -o  to the first grep gets the match <br/>
`73 hosts up` and then we grep only the number out of it

Comment: if i wanted to use `nlanhosts 192.168.0.*` would i just do `nmap -sn $0 | grep...`

Answer (score 1):

You should use a function really, as your chain of commands is more complex than suited for a simple alias.

You could add:

```
nlanhosts() {
    nmap -sn 192.168.0.* | grep "[0-9]* hosts up" | grep -o "[0-9]*"
}
```

to your .bashrc file in the same way you would an alias.

Comment: Chains of piped greps are rarely, if ever, the best approach. In this case `grep "[0-9]* hosts up" | grep -o "[0-9]*"` = `sed -n 's/.*\([0-9]*\) hosts up/\1/p'`

Comment: Please read the question. I already tried this (just to be sure, tried it for third time) and it didn't work.

Comment: @SinaMadani Then you should be asking about the function that didn't work. Using an alias here is just not the right approach.

Comment: Like I said, i tried it as an alias and a function, neither produced the same result as executing the command directly.